# how to enter '0' with checking the key is not empty?

Tags: php, arrays

let me explain my problem..

This is my array

```
$data['id']=1;
$data['name']='Bhavik';
$data['salary']=0;
$data['TA']=0;
```

before processing on the data I am checking whether the key is empty or not if it is empty then we have to neglect it.

like..

```
if(!empty($data['id']))
{
    $responseData['id']=$data['id'];
}
if(!empty($data['name']))
{
    $responseData['name']=$data['name'];
}
if(!empty($data['salary']))
{
    $responseData['salary']=$data['salary'];
}
if(!empty($data['TA']))
{
    $responseData['TA']=$data['TA'];
}

print_r(responseData);
```

it gives me only `id` and `name`
it considers `0` as empty
what if I want `salary` and `TA` with Zero value?

I can do it with checking whether the key is exists or not and the check whether it has any value or not but is there any other way.

I am not using key_exists just because if we pass array like $data['id] without any value still that condition will be true but it gives error bcoz it does not have any value while processing the data.

so any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: So what's a valid empty value then for `TA` and `salary` if it's not `0`?

Comment: if user passes TA without any value

Comment: 0 is considered as empty?

Comment: So check for `if($data['TA'] === '')` or `if(strlen($data['TA']) <= 0)` do you mean with "no value" and empty string or `NULL`?

Comment: yeah there will not be any value

Comment: Does that mean empty string or `NULL`?

Comment: empty (string) or nothing (`NULL`)?

Comment: I am using rest client where in payload I am just giving the key no value so the value field is blank.now I dont know they pass null or string.

Answer (score 1):

you can add second OR condition within `IF` condition statement like

`if(!empty($a) || $a==0)`

Try this hope it will solve your problem

Comment: still there is a problem if I am not passing the TA as a key also its throwing error undefined index TA because we are checking it  0.

Comment: use the following `if(isset($a) && (!empty($a) || $a==0))` since the undefined index error is thrown when the relative key is not found

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function instead of `empty`:

```
function is_blank($value) {
    return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treating the values as strings, check the string length with `strlen()` and the validity of characters inside it, in this case (from the description I assume all-digit values) - `ctype_digit()`.

If you don't know whether the key exists, check that with `isset()`.

Comment: `ctype_digit()` only works if the values are int. Does not work for float values.

Comment: True ... to an extent. To be precise, it only works with **strings** consisting of digits - passing a value of type `int` will return FALSE, hence why I said the values should be treated as strings, casting them if necessary. `ctype_digit()` is just an example, there's no silver bullet.

Comment: *"There's no silver bullet"* - Hmmm, there *might* be. [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: Updated the answer to account for @TiMESPLiNTER's remark.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using strict compare

```
if(null!==$a){
   //... 0 is passed as true value
}
```